# Read X,Y,Z from file, modify tuple / list to unquoted string followed by list

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, coordinates

**Objective:**

Using Python, get `FreeCAD.Vector(223.90,67.99,45.00)` from .txt file.

Comma delimited Text file format:

```
1.0,8.2,9.888
6.345,4.32,2.43
...
```

i.e. X,Y,Z as floats.
A specific application "FreeCAD" uses Python as base scripting language (macros)
The native method to a native FreeCAD object is `Vector` i.e. `FreeCAD.Vector`
the vector is (X,Y,Z) i.e. `FreeCAD.Vector(105453.164062,90917.8671875,1274.77026367)`.

As further detailed example:

```
>>> points=[FreeCAD.Vector(-2.50563430786,0.3603053689,0.0),FreeCAD.Vector(-1.67500686646,0.959897279739,0.0),FreeCAD.Vector(-0.53083139658,0.393310427666,0.0),FreeCAD.Vector(0.767367601395,0.932393193245,0.0)]
>>> line = Draft.makeWire(points,closed=False,face=True,support=None)
>>> Draft.autogroup(line)
```

Here is an example of the `data.txt` file:

```
105507.460938 91080.125 1331.37109375
105509.648438 91077.9375 1326.85534668
105501.375 91072.890625 1318.00634766
105487.0 91070.3984375 1318.89746094
```

Note: the delimiter can be comma or space - it is not important and can be either

**The Problem:**

Creating a variable that has this value:

`[FreeCAD.Vector(-2.50563430786,0.3603053689,0.0),FreeCAD.Vector(-1.67500686646,0.959897279739,0.0),...`

or

Devising a way to assemble the input so the FreeCAD can accept the XYZ input.

**My Code so far:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# 10/26/2017 6:54:16 AM
# For Python, PEP 8 has emerged as the style guide
# http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/intro/learning/
# https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Code_snippets
# https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD
import FreeCAD,Draft,Arch
# In Python, all the statements indented by the same number of character spaces
# after a programming construct are considered to be part of a single block of code.
# Python uses indentation as its method of grouping statements.

## @package Makewire
#  \ingroup ARCH
#  \brief Creates DWire object from file of 3D coordinates
#
#  This program opens a file, reads each space delimited line
#  and draws a dwire object
__title__ = "DWire Import"
__author__ = "Greg Robinson"
__url__ = "http://Lucrosol.com"
# example that works
# p1 = FreeCAD.Vector(0,0,1)
# p2 = FreeCAD.Vector(1,1,2)
# p3 = FreeCAD.Vector(2,4,3)
# Draft.makeWire([p1,p2,p3],closed=False)
# https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Draft_API
# hard coded path & file of coordinates
#    Example:
#105507.460938 91080.125 1331.37109375
#105509.648438 91077.9375 1326.85534668
#105501.375 91072.890625 1318.00634766
#105487.0 91070.3984375 1318.89746094
#105482.851562 91068.8203125 1318.02026367
#105480.5625 91063.5234375 1318.0456543
#105480.351562 90950.0859375 1318.84057617
#105475.992188 90940.046875 1319.13378906
#105473.546875 90933.515625 1318.09472656
#105473.820312 90897.3359375 1321.03942871
#105473.820312 90897.3359375 1321.03942871
#105475.671875 90889.4140625 1276.28381348
#105454.164062 90909.0078125 1274.7479248
#105453.164062 90917.8671875 1274.77026367
# Find & Replace Examples
# x = [s.replace('a', 'b') for s in x]
# words = [w.replace('[br]', '<br />') for w in words]
#
# function readfile
def fileread():
    myfile = open("C:/Users/Greg/Desktop/txt/pipe_example.txt")
    # Create empty set
    global lines
    lines = []
    for l in myfile.readlines():
        lines.append(l)
    myfile.close()
fileread()
# End readfile function

# contents of file are now in list
# Note
# Lists are enclosed in square brackets ([ and ]) and tuples in parentheses (( and )).
numbers = []
dwire_list = []
# Process list from file into float then get them into vectors
for line in lines:
    newline = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
    dwire_list.append(newline)
# append the processed items together

a_list = []
coords = []
count = len(dwire_list)
while (count > 0):
   coord0 = FreeCAD.Vector(dwire_list[count - 1])
   coords.append(coord0)
   count = count - 1
#
print "Loop Executed, Dwire should have appeared on file"
# Creat Dwire
# Draft.makeWire(coords,closed=False)
#     "makePipe([baseobj,diameter,length,placement,name]): creates an pipe object from the given base object"
# Create Dwire
Draft.makeWire(points,closed=False,face=True,support=None)
print coords
line = Draft.makeWire(coords,closed=False,face=True,support=None)
FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.recompute()
```

However:

Generally the question of how to make such a hybrid string list is elusive to me.

I'm at this stage or working through the issue:

```
## Open the file with read only permit
# f = open('C:/Users/Greg/Desktop/txt/pipe_example_s.txt', "r")

## use readlines to read all lines in the file
## The variable "lines" is a list containing all lines
#lines = f.read().splitlines()


with open('C:/Users/Greg/Desktop/txt/pipe_example_c.txt') as f:
    mylist = [tuple(map(float, i.split(','))) for i in f]

## close the file after reading the lines.
#f.close()
print mylist
print "One"
print mylist[0]

p1 = 34.8999
print "FreeCAD.Vector (%s)" % '34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665'

p1 = "FreeCAD.Vector (%s)" % '34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665'
print p1

p2 = 123.456
p1 = "FreeCAD.Vector (%s)" % (p2) + '34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665'
print p1


p3 = tuple(mylist)
print p3

s = '(0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923)'
s = s.replace(',', 'FreeCAD.Vector ')
print(s)  # -> [0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]

print mylist[1]
```

Which outputs:

```
[(102360.003871, 92614.733022, 1114.159952), (102360.045926, 92613.778689, 1114.097542), (102361.109418, 92613.926808, 1114.123386), (102360.90909, 92614.061128, 1144.246289), (102360.008406, 92614.203715, 1144.217125), (102360.073353, 92615.032739, 1145.531946), (102338.988007, 92623.107091, 1113.028396), (102339.457605, 92623.63571, 1113.615987), (102339.991842, 92624.037633, 1112.722525), (102305.610817, 92666.076043, 1112.399744), (102306.151843, 92666.628226, 1112.942683), (102306.687078, 92666.984192, 1112.139385), (102323.38305, 92643.109377, 1112.511513), (102323.824052, 92643.468957, 1113.20053), (102324.553584, 92643.911892, 1112.594155), (102359.99434, 92614.715556, 1113.832716), (102359.998296, 92613.819679, 1113.790412), (102361.103982, 92613.907801, 1113.974154), (102361.095313, 92614.148855, 1129.857483), (102359.940314, 92614.062477, 1129.823867), (102360.029689, 92614.917234, 1130.076275), (102360.090856, 92614.626343, 1145.496362), (102360.454485, 92613.963864, 1145.244853), (102361.020532, 92614.211705, 1145.234733)]
One
(102360.003871, 92614.733022, 1114.159952)
FreeCAD.Vector (34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665)
FreeCAD.Vector (34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665)
FreeCAD.Vector (123.456)34.8999, 2.8997, 3.09665
((102360.003871, 92614.733022, 1114.159952), (102360.045926, 92613.778689, 1114.097542), (102361.109418, 92613.926808, 1114.123386), (102360.90909, 92614.061128, 1144.246289), (102360.008406, 92614.203715, 1144.217125), (102360.073353, 92615.032739, 1145.531946), (102338.988007, 92623.107091, 1113.028396), (102339.457605, 92623.63571, 1113.615987), (102339.991842, 92624.037633, 1112.722525), (102305.610817, 92666.076043, 1112.399744), (102306.151843, 92666.628226, 1112.942683), (102306.687078, 92666.984192, 1112.139385), (102323.38305, 92643.109377, 1112.511513), (102323.824052, 92643.468957, 1113.20053), (102324.553584, 92643.911892, 1112.594155), (102359.99434, 92614.715556, 1113.832716), (102359.998296, 92613.819679, 1113.790412), (102361.103982, 92613.907801, 1113.974154), (102361.095313, 92614.148855, 1129.857483), (102359.940314, 92614.062477, 1129.823867), (102360.029689, 92614.917234, 1130.076275), (102360.090856, 92614.626343, 1145.496362), (102360.454485, 92613.963864, 1145.244853), (102361.020532, 92614.211705, 1145.234733))
(0.0034596999FreeCAD.Vector  0.0034775001FreeCAD.Vector  0.0010091923)
(102360.045926, 92613.778689, 1114.097542)
```

Comment: Please check out our help center. Specifically, how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have given far too much information, so your question is fairly unclear.

Comment: After the `s = s.replace(',', 'FreeCAD.Vector ')`, the result printed should be `(0.0034596999FreeCAD.Vector  0.0034775001FreeCAD.Vector  0.0010091923)`, **Not** what's shown currently near the end of your question. Please [edit] your question and create a **minimal** example that illustrates the problem you're encountering (and does so correctly).

Comment: It looks like FreeCAD can import from CSV directly. Why do you need to write code to do it? Or does this not create FreeCAD Vectors? https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Spreadsheet_CSV

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you need help with, but perhaps this will give you some ideas that might help you to solve the problem:

```
>>> def vector(x, y, z):
...     print("vector: x=%f, y=%f, z=%f" % (x, y, z))
... 
>>> vector(1, 2, 3)
vector: x=1.000000, y=2.000000, z=3.000000
>>> v = [1, 2, 3]
>>> vector(*v)
vector: x=1.000000, y=2.000000, z=3.000000
```